# SQL Server: group_by select active dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my table I have two columns:

- `leasecontract.[Contract Activation Date]`
- `leasecontract.[Contract Ending Date]`

With those two columns, I'd like to generate a table for example like this:

[image]

So the query for the first row could be (new contracts):

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(leasecontract.Id) AS total,
   YEAR(leasecontract.[Contract Activation Date]) AS jaar  
FROM 
   leasecontract
GROUP BY 
   YEAR(leasecontract.[Contract Activation Date])
```

But is there a way to do the same with the middle row? To show the active contracts grouped by year in 1 query. Thanks!

SQL version is 2008

Comment: How do you define active contracts?

Comment: Active contract -> when activation date is in the same year or before and ending date is after year or in the same...

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: And how do you define new contracts?
Your sample query for new contracts just uses all contracts?

Comment: The query gets by year the contracts that are activated. So in this case the query gets all contracts and order them by year...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never did a recursive CTE before. But this was a good place to learn. So, the one below should work. In case there's a contract with no end date, it will show as "active" on all listed years following its start date. That's assuming your SQL Server version is 2008 or above, I think.

The recursion may not be necessary, but in theory just getting DISTINCT years from start and end dates, it would be possible for there to be leap years where no new contracts were opened, or old ones closed, while they would still be active. This way, even leap years will be included, plus min/max will likely surpass DISTINCT / GROUP BY dates where performance is concerned.

```
;WITH DateLimits AS 
    -- Fetching absolute MIN and MAX date
        (SELECT MinDate, CASE WHEN MaxDate < MaxDateCheck THEN MaxDateCheck ELSE MaxDate END AS MaxDate
        FROM
            (SELECT MIN([Contract Activation Date]) MinDate
                , MAX([Contract Ending Date]) MaxDate
                , MAX([Contract Activation Date]) MaxDateCheck
            FROM LEASECONTRACT) SRC)
    -- Creating all years between MIN start and MAX endtime
    , CTESeq AS
        (SELECT YEAR(MinDate) [Year]
        FROM DateLimits
        UNION ALL
        SELECT [Year]+1
        FROM CTESeq 
        JOIN DateLimits ON 1=1
        WHERE [Year] < YEAR(MaxDate))
-- Forming the results based on CTESeq above
SELECT *
FROM CTESeq CTE
OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) [New Contracts] FROM LEASECONTRACT WHERE YEAR([Contract Activation Date]) = CTE.Year) OAStarts
OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) [Active Contracts] FROM LEASECONTRACT 
    WHERE CTE.Year BETWEEN YEAR([Contract Activation Date]) AND ISNULL(YEAR([Contract Ending Date]),CTE.Year)) OAActive
OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) [Closed Contracts] FROM LEASECONTRACT WHERE YEAR([Contract Ending Date]) = CTE.Year) OAEnds
ORDER BY [Year] ASC
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 100);
```

**EDIT**: Added a check in case MAX endtime is actually smaller than MAX starttime.

**EDIT 2**: Holy, NePh's multiple CTE queries example was superb. Didn't know you can do that. I changed my response to a single query by his example, replacing the previous variables with an additional CTE select instead.

Comment: Thanks for this great query! 1 query for all is much better.  Unfortunately the result is empty: array(0) { }

Comment: Edited once more by NePh's example below. Now it's a single, clean query. Should be quite efficient performance-wise, too. :)

Comment: Np, thank @NePh by voting his up too, since this was a team effort. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would do this with three common table expressions.
One for each column you want to select. Then join them together using the year.

I´m not sure if I understood your conditions regarding the status of a contract (new, active and closed) correctly. But you can adapt the `WERE`-conditions in each commom table expression pretty easy.

```
WITH    newContracts
          AS ( SELECT   total = COUNT(l.Id) ,
                        [Year] = YEAR(GETDATE())
               FROM     leasecontract l
               WHERE    GETDATE() < l.[Contract Activation Date]
               GROUP BY YEAR(GETDATE())
             ),
        activeContracts
          AS ( SELECT   total = COUNT(l.Id) ,
                        [Year] = YEAR(l.[Contract Activation Date])
               FROM     leasecontract l
               WHERE    GETDATE() >= l.[Contract Activation Date]
                        AND GETDATE() < l.[Contract Ending Date]
               GROUP BY YEAR(l.[Contract Activation Date])
             ),
        closedContracts
          AS ( SELECT   total = COUNT(l.Id) ,
                        [Year] = YEAR(l.[Contract Ending Date])
               FROM     leasecontract l
               WHERE    GETDATE() >= l.[Contract Ending Date]
               GROUP BY YEAR(l.[Contract Ending Date])
             )
    SELECT  n.[Year] ,
            n.total AS [New contracts] ,
            a.total AS [Active contracts] ,
            c.total AS [Closed contracts]
    FROM    newContracts n
            JOIN activeContracts a ON n.[Year] = a.[Year]
            JOIN closedContracts c ON a.[Year] = c.[Year]
```

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know you could do this with CTE's. Adds a whole new perspective. :)